# Tensorflow GPU - Spyder

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having a problem with importing tensorflow GPU on spyder. 
This is what I get when I type import tensorflow on iPython using Spyder 3 (on MacOS)

[image]

When I checked what packages I have within tensorflow I get this list, which I see that iPython, and Spyder are not included.

[image]

Also in anaconda, when I click on tensorflow in Environments, I have the option to open it with Python, with terminal, but not with iPython or Spyder (or Jupyter)

[image]

I would very much appreciate any help.

UPDATE 1:

Ok I managed to get Spyder on tensorflow's ENV but when I run the command 'import tensorflow' on iPython I get this error (when I run the same command on Python's tab everything seems to work just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I solved this mystery. If you have installed Spyder from the Anaconda, go to the Anaconda launcher. There go to environments, you will see two of them: root and tensorflow. The latter one is created due to the instructions by tensorflow.org. Just run all those instructions on the root, don't activate tensorflow environment, it will work. Everything will be available in spyder.

Comment: Could you please clarify what does "run all those instructions on the root" mean. Since Anaconda Launcher has been replaced by Anaconda Navigator, the UI might be different, so I cannot find any `run` things. Thanks.

Comment: My method is quite not perfect and not recommended at all but at least it works for me. In Anaconda Navigator, open the environments tab and delete the tensorflow environment. Use the default root environment and complete the steps on the tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) in the root environment. Somehow, the Spyder only detects the packages that are in the root only.

Answer (score 4):

The instructions mentioned on the (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) link do NOT work for the Ananconda/Spyder setups on windows. Having struggled through this for hours below is the easiest solution to get this working. Hope this helps!

Basically you do NOT need to create a seperate tensorflow environment if you want to run this on spyder. Use the below commands to install tensorflow on the ananconda client.

1) Open the Ananconda prompt from the installation folder in the start menu.
2) Run below commands:

```
conda install pyqt
conda install tensorflow
```

Comment: This worked great for me.  However, you need to make sure you launch Anaconda Prompt as administrator.  I'm also not sure if this matters or not, but I used "conda install tensorflow-gpu" because I wanted to make sure it would use GPU....

Comment: Yes, you need to launch as administrator. More recently, I figured out how to get this working. Once you create the tensorflow enviroment you can **Spyder(Tensorflow)** in your ananconda start menu folder. If you run your code by opening this the tensorflow should work.

Answer (score 2):

Spyder is picking up the default Anaconda Env, whereas you have tensorflow install in a separate environment `tensorflow`

To work with Spyder & tensorflow, install tensor flow and openssl in default ENV

Comment: Thanks but because I am brand new on that I have no idea how to do it. I followed the instructions on tensorflow site. Wouldn't be easier to just add ipython and Spyder on tensorflow env?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but I would prefer the other way. I have all the required condo packages in the default ENV, and then new ENV just subsets of default;

I update the default Anaconda Channel to add [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.github.io), followed by `conda update conda` and `conda update anaconda`, followed by `conda install tensorflow`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to get this working using the instruction on Tensorflow link. Once you create the tensorflow enviroment you can **Spyder(Tensorflow)** in your ananconda start menu folder. If you run your code by opening this the tensorflow should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Anaconda Navigator:
It works for me in a different way: 
As tensorflow is separately created environment, install spyder in tensorflow envirnment. 
(Anaconda>Home>Applications on>*tensorflow*>spyder>install ... wait for installation to complete and ten launch)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen another issue in anaconda. If you install Tensor flow in root or custom environment (like 'tensorflow') its not accessible from jupyter notebook or spyder. The best way to do this is to install it in the administrator mode. Follow these steps:

1. Open "Anaconda Prompt" as an administrator.
2. Verify the status on top written "Administrator: Anaconda Prompt"
3. DON'T Activate any of the environments, root or tensorflow.
4. Type in the command "pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu" to install Tensorflow with GPU support.
5. To install Keras type "conda install -c conda-forge keras"
6. To verify installation, type 'python' and then inside python env. type 'import tensorflow as tf'. If all is well it will work without error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and solved by performing following steps in order.

Assuming that you have created `conda` `environment`, installed `tensorflow` and activated it and also installed `spyder`.

Check the executable python of your conda environment

```
>>import sys
>>sys.executable
```

Note the path of `python` executable.

Go to Spyder preferences and set the interpreter path to the one noted above.